# Vertical line spanning fraction

Tags: math-mode, equations

I would like to write the following equation:

[image]

How do I produce the vertical line and the subscript 'iso-effect'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\textrm{RBE}=\left.\frac{D_{\textrm{photon}}}{D_{\textrm{test}}}\right\rvert_{\textrm{iso-effect}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `-` in “iso-effect” is probably not a minus sign, but an ordinary hyphen, thus `\textrm` is the better choice (the same applies for “photon” and “test” as well). I would also move `\left.` to the left of `\frac` (it doesn’t change the output but is probably semantically correct).

Comment: looks to me like the "RBE" should also be `\textrm`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Looking at the provided figure, I think you are right. Edited.

Comment: Yes, RBE is not a variable.